# Image replacement using PDFBox is showing garbled image

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox 2.0.8 to replace image in pdf document. My process includes extract the image from document and write to file system. Compress the image which has been extracted. Compressed image needs to be replaced with the original image. However, after replacement PDF is showing garbled image. Refer page# 1 at the link 
https://35.200.235.243/compression/download?fileName=/outbox/pdf/test123/test1-compress.pdf. If i will open this document in Chrome then it seems to be better. However, on desktop it is garbled. In chrome the background color seems to have changed. However, there is no mask in this object

```
for (COSName xObjectName : resources.getXObjectNames()) {
                    PDXObject xObject = resources.getXObject(xObjectName);
                    if (xObject instanceof PDImageXObject) {

                        imageCounter++;
                        System.out.println("cosname="+xObjectName.toString());
                        PDImageXObject original_img = ((PDImageXObject) xObject);
                 String suffix = original_img.getSuffix();
                        File imageFile = new File(destPath+"/"+"image"+imageCounter+"."+suffix);
                        int imageWidth = original_img.getWidth();
                        int imageHeight = original_img.getHeight();
                        BufferedImage bImage = new BufferedImage(imageWidth,imageHeight,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                        bImage = original_img.getOpaqueImage();
                        ImageIO.write(bImage,suffix, imageFile);
                if(suffix.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg") || suffix.equalsIgnoreCase("jpeg")) {

                            System.out.println("found jpg="+imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                            CompressPDFJPEG compress    =   new CompressPDFJPEG(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), directoryID);
                            HashMap compressedFilesMap  =   compress.getCompressedFiles();
                            String compressedFiles []   =   (String[]) compressedFilesMap.get("compressedFiles");
                            String replaceImageFile     =   "";
                            for (int i=0;i<compressedFiles.length;i++) {

                                if (compressedFiles[i] != null) {
                                    replaceImageFile = compressedFiles[i];
                                PDImageXObject replacement_img = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(replaceImageFile, doc);
                                resources.put(xObjectName, replacement_img);
                                    doc.save(outFileName);
                                break;
                                }

                            }
                        }

                        if(suffix.equalsIgnoreCase("png")) {

                            CompressPDFPNG compress     =   new CompressPDFPNG(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), directoryID);
                            HashMap compressedFilesMap  =   compress.compressPNG();
                            String compressedFiles []   =   (String[]) compressedFilesMap.get("compressedFiles");
                            String replaceImageFile     =   "";
                            for (int i=0;i<compressedFiles.length;i++) {

                                if (compressedFiles[i] != null) {
                                    replaceImageFile = compressedFiles[i];
                                    PDImageXObject replacement_img = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(replaceImageFile, doc);
                                        resources.put(xObjectName, replacement_img);
                                    break;
                                }

                            }


                        }


                    }        
                }
            }

     doc.close();
```

Here are the different links
Original PDF:**https://35.200.235.243/compression/download?fileName=/inbox/pdf/test1.pdf**
Image Extracted     :   **https://35.200.235.243/compression/download?fileName=/work/pdf/test123/image2.jpg**

Compressed Image    :   **https://35.200.235.243/compression/download?fileName=/work/pdf/test123/image2-compress1.jpg**
Compressed PDF      :   **https://35.200.235.243/compression/download?fileName=/outbox/pdf/test123/test1-compress.pdf**

Desktop Screen Shot (Compressed PDF):

[image]

Comment: page 2 doesn't have any image. Only page #1 has an image, with two guys looking at a popup window on some equipment.

Comment: It would be helpful if you include screenshots explaining what you were expecting, and what you got instead.

Comment: Yes...It is page#1. I also done a edit to my question with the different links

Comment: I only get *"File /work/pdf/test123/test2.jpg Is Not Present .....!"*  and *"File /inbox/pdf/test123/test1.pdf Is Not Present .....!"* for the "Original PDF" and the "Image Extracted". Furthermore I see no problems in `test1-compress.pdf`.

Comment: Link corrected. Open the compressed pdf on desktop. I have given a link in the original question. The image will be garbled

Comment: Open the compressed PDF in Chrome browser. Image is not garbled, but background has changed from white to black. In the original PDF mask is coming as null

Comment: ***A)*** Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the *garbled image issue* - I get the image with a black background but without the garbling you observe. I use Adobe Acrobat Reader DC version 2018.011.20040. ***B)*** Your source PDF `test1.pdf` is identical to the PDF `5992-0891EN.pdf` you shared in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48628749/1729265), and already there you were informed that the image *does* have a mask.

Comment: All the example provided for mask are related to PNG image. However, the image on page#1 is jpeg image. I used method getSuffix(). This method returned "jpg". Hence, not able to understand how to apply mask on a jpeg image. Is it possible that getSuffix method can return wrong image type

Comment: In a PDF masks (either hard or soft) can be used with any type of image. Probably examples focus on PNG images because regular PNGs can also contain an alpha channel which regular JPEGs cannot (at least not in a native and widely supported way). When embedded in a PDF, though, the alpha channel is stored separately (with JPEG2000 it may remain embedded in the image).

Comment: I just tried with PDFBox 1.8.0 imageInPdf.getCOSStream().replaceWithStream(newImage.getCOSStream());. This seems to have worked. Mask was automatically created. No issue with background color. However, if i use IOUtils.copy from PDFBox 2.0.8 then it does seem to have the same effect

Comment: Thank you all. I was able to successfully replace the file with the below mentioned code. However, i have another query. I noticed that the replacement file is 50% in the size, but there was no decrease in size of PDF. Let me know if i need to open a new question                                                        BufferedImage  buffered_replacement_image_file = ImageIO.read(new File(replacement_image_file));
PDImageXObject replacement_img = JPEGFactory.createFromImage(doc, buffered_replacement_image_file);
resources.put(xObjectName, replacement_img);